# Connect an on premise Oracle Database to PowerApps

Tags: powerapp, database, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, oracle

I have an Oracle Database created using Oracle Express Edition 18c and Oracle SQL Developer. It's name is 'my_powerapps_connection' and created a table named 'EMPData'.

[image]
[image]

For the connection properties please refer to the below screen capture.
[image]

I have installed both On-Premises Gateway and On-Premises Gateway(personal mode) as instructed in the below article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-oracledb

- Username: sys
- Role: SYSDBA
- Authentication Type: Default
- Hostname:    localhost
- Port: 1521
- SID: xe

When I tried to connect the Oracle Database I used the 'Oracle Database connector for the server name I used localhost.

[image]

Once I clicked the 'Connect' button I got the below error message

[image]

I want to know what I have done wrong.

Best regards,
Chiranthaka

Comment: install oracle client and try , refer here - https://createsitecollection.medium.com/connect-oracle-with-on-premise-data-gateway-1bb742d8a0cc